# How to integrate $(x+y) \ dx + (x-y) \ dy$ over an ellipse?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, manifolds, greens-theorem

> Show that the ellipse defined by the equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a submanifold and orient it counterclockwise. Compute $\int_M \omega$ for $\omega := (x+y) \ dx + (x-y) \ dy$, where $x$ and $y$ refer the standard coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Here is what I got so far:

We consider $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}$ and note that $f \in \mathcal{C}^1$ and $f^{-1}(1)$ is equal to our ellipse. Since $Df = \nabla f$ has rank $1$ the Regular Value Theorem implies that our ellipse $E$ is a $1$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

However, I am not sure how to evaluate the integral $\int_M \omega$. I would be tempted to use Green's Theorem $\oint_{\partial M} P(x,y) \ dx + Q(x,y) \ dy = \int_M \big( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \big) \ dxdy$.

But when I use Green's Theorem I get

$$P(x,y) := x+y, \quad\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 1$$
$$Q(x,y) := x-y, \quad \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = 1$$
$$\oint_M P(x,y) \ dx + Q(x,y) \ dy = \int_M \bigg( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \bigg) \ dxdy = \int_M 0 \ dxdy = 0.$$

Could you please tell me if this is right?

Comment: The result is correct, except for a notational error - you should write $\oint_{E}$ where $E = \partial M$ with the corresponding orientation. In particular the integral doesn't depend on the shape of the curve.

Comment: The reason why the integral always evaluates to zero is because the form $\omega$ is a sum of a holomorphic and antiholomorphic form, $\omega = \frac{1+i}{4} zdz + \frac{1-i}{4} \bar z d \bar z$, which integrate to zero because of [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).